# How to extend an object with angular.extend?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to extend an object in angularJs using multiple ajax calls results. However only the last results extends my empty object.

```
$rootScope.progress = {}; // the objkect to extend

$http.get('data.json').
then(function(result){angular.extend($rootScope.progress,result.data)}),

$http.get('error.json').
then(function(result){angular.extend($rootScope.progress,result.data)}),

$http.get('data2.json').
then(function(result){angular.extend($rootScope.progress,result.data)}),

$http.get('data3.json').
then(function(result)    {angular.extend($rootScope.progress,result.data)})
```

You could see a plunker here:http://plnkr.co/edit/iDmsTpDpFUnvrv1pCUU9?p=preview

Comment: You don't actually make any calls to extend in your plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because all your data return is array instead of object.

Changed all the data.json to object.

Refer to http://plnkr.co/edit/Gq22dsksxlPYCryM1BOs?p=preview

If your json always return array, then your $scope.result should changed to array.

you can use `$scope.result = $scope.result.concat(value.data);`